# Compute Curl Integral of Vector Field and Ellipse

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider a vector field : ${\bf F}=P(x){\bf i}+ Q(y){\bf j}$, for some functions : $P(x), Q(y)$ which have continuous partial derivatives everywhere.

Let: $C$ stand for the ellipse : $\{ 4x^2+9y^2=1\}$. Then : $\int_C {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}$
 equals:

I can't determine an answer with this data but the options are: 
 $P(\frac{1}{2}) - Q(\frac{1}{2}), 0, P(\frac{1}{2}),P(\frac{1}{2}) + Q(\frac{1}{2})$

Which is the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$\nabla \times \mathbf F = \dfrac{\partial Q(y)}{\partial x} - \dfrac{\partial P(x)}{\partial y} = 0; \tag 1$

next recall that, *via* Stokes theorem,

$\displaystyle \int_\xi \nabla \times \mathbf F dA = \int_{\partial \xi} \mathbf F \cdot d \mathbf r = \int_C \mathbf F \cdot d \mathbf r, \tag 2$

since

$\partial \xi = C; \tag 3$

here $\xi$ is the region bounded by the ellipse $C$, and $dA$ is the area element on $\Bbb R^2$.  Together (1) and (2) yield

$\displaystyle \int_C \mathbf F \cdot d \mathbf r = 0, \tag 4$

which is thus the correct option.

Comment: How do you obtain that the field is irrotational when we don't know what $P$ and $Q$ are?

Comment: @Allawonder;  well, $P(x)$ usually means $P$ is a function of $x$ alone, not of $y$, so $\partial P(x) / \partial y = $ and so forth.  Cheers!

Comment: Oh, of course! LOL.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* You're supposed to use Green's theorem, so that your integral is equal to $$\iint_{\mathcal E} (Q_x-P_y)\mathrm dx \mathrm dy,$$ with $\mathcal E$ being the region determined by the ellipse. Can you continue now?